# Write a code to find the value of e3.1 in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Write a code to find the value of e3.1 in PL/SQL? please help me

```
DECLARE 
   Test_Number number := 3;
   
BEGIN 
   dbms_output.put_line(EXP(Test_Number number)); 
   
END;
```

Comment: If you use PL/SQL, then it is Oracle, not MySQL (or vice versa). So, which database do you use? Fix tags, please. As of the question itself: what is value of "e3.1"? What is "e3.1"? What result do you expect? How is it to be calculated?

Comment: EXP function does not expect you to provide the datatype number.

Comment: PL/SQL Developer is a desktop application. You should only tag it if you have issues with that application specifically.

Answer (score 0):

In oracle, this works:

```
set serveroutput on size 999999
DECLARE 
   l_test_number number := 3;
   
BEGIN 
   dbms_output.put_line(EXP(l_test_number)); 
   
END; 
/

20.08553692318766774092852965458171789706


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Note 1: Added the `set serveroutput on size 999999` to ensure the result of `dbms_output.put_line` gets printed to the screen.

Note 2: Changed the variable name - pl/sql is not case sensitive so camel case can be confusing and as a best practice I prefixed the variable with 'l_' - indicating this is a local variable. These changes are not needed for the example to work.

Comment: There are 2 differences between this code and the OP's code are both changes needed?

Comment: @P.Salmon good point I added some explanation

Comment: Missed that - the change I meant was to the exp function call (inclusion of number) it is possible though that OP may not have enabled dbms_output , OP doesn't say nor does he/she mention any erors.